# Rearranging the order of the list by drag and drop GUI

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I have a List that I gather from reading XMLs with XStream. And I want to print the name of each element using JList. What I want to do is to be able to select multiple elements and change their order by dragging them to another position in that list. I know how to do the same thing by selecting multiple elements and adding 2 more buttons (up and down) to move them in the list but I have no idea how to do the same without any buttons, just dragging and dropping. Which topics I should research? Is it even possible with JList? Does it have something to do with eventlisteners?

Comment: Duly noted. Here's a possible answer https://community.oracle.com/message/5726865

Comment: Thanks @HernánErasmo and Dmitri, I got it working now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.